# Подписывание программы android

Tags: android, java

Такая проблема случилась, подписал программу одним ключом, потом залил в маркет программу, потом я дописал еще пару фитчей в программе, и снова подписал создав другой нвоый ключ, а старый удалил, теперь в маркете пишет что мол нужен старый ключ, а с этим пойди погуляй. Что мне сделать что бы можно было залить с новым ключем? Или как мне сделать тот старый. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

учи тебя.. учи.. =) тебе ночью объяснял про версии, а ты взял и все поломал =)

> "Будьте аккуратны с созданным ключом.
> Именно он является гарантией, что
> новая версия программы написана вами.
> Поэтому, если вы потеряете созданный
> ключ, вам придется выкладывать
> программу под другим именем с новым
> ключом."

Comment: кстати, тебя на хабре недавно хвалил =), а ты... =)

Answer (score 1):

Это все - сливай воду... Придется выкладывать прогу под новым именем (пакетом) и подписывать новым ключом.

Вариантов нет - вы не первый и видимо не последний...

Comment: хреновенько.. спасибо за помощь